# Data table python flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a question regarding mysql db python table in Bootstrap.

My question is my data is not shown in the table. I can see it gets data because of when I add row in mysql db with data the table increases.

app.py code:

```
@app.route('/dashboard')
@is_logged_in
def dashboard():
       #create cursor
    cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
    #Get data
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
    data=cur.fetchall()
    if result > 0:
        return render_template('dashboard.html', data=data)
    else:
        msg = 'No DOC Found'
        return render_template('dashboard.html', msg=msg)
    #close connection
    cur.close()
    return render_template('dashboard.html' )
```

.html

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
              <tr>
                   <th>data1</th>
                   <th>data2</th>
              </tr>
              {% for test in data%}
              <tr>
                   <td>{{test.rdno}}</td>
                   <td>{{test.ipno}}</td>

                {% endfor %}
              </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Have you checked this question for a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845102/using-mysql-in-flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
<td>{{test.rdno}}</td>
<td>{{test.ipno}}</td>
```

do this

```
  <td>{{test[0]}}</td>
  <td>{{test[1]}}</td>
```