# variable is undefined flask mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I need to greet user on the page. F.ex: Hello {{ name }}, but I get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'account' referenced before assignment`. What is the problem in the code below?

`python:`

```
app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO users(name, email) VALUES(%s, %s)', (name, email))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return redirect('profile')

    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')

        account = cur.fetchone()

    return render_template('profile.html', account=account)
```

`index.html:`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <span style="color: #fff;">Firstname:</span><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type your firstname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

`profile.html`

```
<h4 style="color: #fff;">Your firstname: is {{ account['name'] }}</h4>
<h4 style="color: #fff;">Your email: is {{ account['email'] }}</h4>
```

I can connect to database and fetch users data, but on the `profile.html` page I get the error
How to solve it? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried the search engine? It's really good. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845102/using-mysql-in-flask

Comment: @Hoppo, could you please check again the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't passed the account to the template.

Instead of ,

```py
return render_template('profile.html')
```

you need to write as,

```py
return render_template('profile.html', account=account)
```

EDIT:

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')

        account = cur.fetchone()

        return render_template('profile.html', account=account)
```

Or if you wanted the profile to be a get request you can do this

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')

    account = cur.fetchone()

    return render_template('profile.html', account=account)
```

Comment: and now I get this error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'account' referenced before assignment`

Comment: can you correct the indentation as i have edited the answer :)

Comment: and make sure to enable the POST method in the route too.

Comment: and now I get this error`The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.` It doesnt see profile.html.

Comment: check the latest edits :)  I didn't know you were checking in GET requests. Try it now.

Comment: in the last version profile.html opens, but there is no any text.

Comment: make sure entries exist in the users table of the database :) and they have name and email fields.

Comment: there is no problem with db. I have checked it, I can `add` data there, but can `get` only first row. How to get new row for every new user?

Comment: do you have any primary key ( integer ) which get incremented when new user is added ? 
if your field is named as id, you can do like this. change id as you wish.
change the `cur = mysql.connection.cursor()`
into `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC')`