# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock when running flask app from terminal

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, flask

There are literally tons of answers, which involve installing `mysql-server` in ubuntu. But I am using **XAMPP** and I am able to access mysql server through browser. I want the convenience of both PHPmyadmin and xampp and running flask app from terminal. For some reason, it is giving me the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

I am extremely new to ubuntu and I will grateful if someone tells me how to link xampp mysql server to ubuntu terminal. I simply could not find an answer for this particular answer. My `mysql.sock` file is in `/opt/lammp/var/mysql/` folder, if that helps.

Any help regarding this really appreciated.

EDIT: I have added the following lines my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
 
socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock 
 
[client]
 
socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But the error message is not changing.

EDIT: This error seems to be only occurring in flask application with the library `flask-mysqldb`. `mysql-connector` in python is functioning as expected.

Comment: It looks like this is mostly answered in [Using MySQL in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845102/using-mysql-in-flask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll apparently have to tell flask the proper path to the socket file (`/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, as you know; currently it seems to be looking at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`).

[According to the documentation](https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you'll need to use the `MYSQL_UNIX_SOCKET` configuration directive along with your other directives for setting things like the username, password, etc, such as `app.config['MYSQL_UNIX_SOCKET'] = '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock'`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784451/2385479) should point you in the right direction.